# Nested DTO requirement

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, entity, nhibernate-mapping, spring-rest

I need Employee Object in response which contains role object and user object manager as a fields.
I need to show only few fields of manager and role object.
I'm not sure how to achieve it while displaying Employee DTO.

Please help me on this

```
public class Employee  {

    private String employeeID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Set<Role> roles;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String type;
    private boolean isEnable;
    private Employee supervisor;
    private List<Branch> branches;
}
```

I need only name and email of manager and few field of Role object

Comment: I'll simply make a separate responseDTO which will just contain required fields. Other way out is to set only those fields in EmployeeDTO which are required leaving others to null.

Comment: @Sanket how are you going to map it ,please let me know, I have created differentVo for the object fields but how am i going to map,a little code would help

Comment: In my project, I use mapstruct for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming you choose to use separate ResponseDTO.***

You can use mapstruct to map your EmployeeDTO to ResponseDTO something like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring") 
public interface EmployeeMapper { 
    ResponseDTO getResponseDTOFromEmployeeDTO(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO); 
}
```

Also if your ResponseDTO contains different field names than your EmployeeDTO then you can map them as below.

Let suppose in your EmployeeDTO you have ***employeeId*** and in your ResponseDTO you have ***id***.

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") 
    public interface EmployeeMapper { 
        @Mappings({@Mapping(target = "id", source = "employeeId")})
        ResponseDTO getResponseDTOFromEmployeeDTO(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO); 
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Don't forget to put the required dependencies in your pom.